# Game made by Google maps: marker loop, marker image changing and crossing table

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm working to get a small game in google maps api v3, an easy "Drag'n'drop" marker (a waste) to put in the right container (so another marker).

here's what I did till now http://www.nadersafwan.site90.net/minijeu.html

here are my achievements:
I managed to put all the map parameters
to create the points, 8 fix points and 1 draggable,
to have a random position for my dragable marker,
I've set timeout and points,...

all I want now is to create a sort of loop, which clear the old marker (with defined properties) and to show another marker (with his own image and NAME): this may be executed every time those variables correspond in both (mobile and fix markers) and at a certain distance.

so I need: 
1 - a function which says that at XY px of distance and if the kind of marker is the same type, and then which creates a loop who clears up the old marker attributes and gives a new one with the new attributes

2 - a function which design a random type of waste and which gives the related attributes (image and name) to the dragable marker

what i have:
1 - distance between markers (euclidean distance):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {  
    for (var i = 0; i < point_tab.length; i++) {
        if (i in point_tab) {
            var d = point_tab[i];
            var dlat = d.coords.lat();
            var dlng = d.coords.lng();
            var dist = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(lat - dlat, 2) + Math.pow(lng - dlng, 2) );
            console.log(dist);
            for (i in types_dechets) {marker.setIcon(point_tab[i].image)}
                if (dist < 0.01) {
            alert("youpie");
                clearOverlays();
                marker.setMap(map);
            }
        }
}
if (dechetterie_trouvee == false) {
    alert("pollueur");
    }  
}
```

All I need here is to add a variable confrontation inside the 'point_tab' Array between the values of the dragableMarker and the fixMarkers already defined as "point_tab[n].nom" variable.
Here I use the 'clearoverlays()' function to clear the marker, but 'marker.setMap(map)' gives me a different image only once, I want it to changing every time my marker get cleared

2 - for a random waste type choice I tried out this:

```
for (n in point_tab) {
var random_type_dechet = function() {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * point_tab[n].length);
return point_tab[randomIndex].image;
}
}
```

I don't really understand this so much but, it may change randomly the type of waste in the 'point_tab' Array, probably to be implemented with the previous script to get always a different dragableMarker?

Comment: Nader...Need some clarification.  You have markers that will change based on proximity? you need a loop to go back and clean this up? You need a listener? to wait for marker changes via drag and drop?  Also (problem) your main link to your example is producing an error and redirecting to the webhost.  Maybe you should create a jsfiddle and add what you have and give a link so we can see what you current have.